# Recursive feature elimination

Tags: feature-selection

I am confused that the recursive feature elimination is supervise or unsupervised? In other words, can we use the recursive feature elimination technique on a dataset with no class labels? Any comments thanks

Comment: "Recursive feature elimination" is too broad a term. There are both supervised and unsupervised methods that we can classify as such. Perhaps you should describe or mention the exact algorithm you are dealing with.